# How to search for multiple names on different rows where first name and last name on different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

| ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SARA | JAMES |
| 5 | STEVE | STEPHEN |
| 2 | KAL | LEE |
| 33 | TONY | KAMPLOO |
| 3 | SANDRA | BROWN |
| 23 | HOPE | WHITE |

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| SARA | JAMES |

I have 2 tables:

Table1 has ID, First names and last names like the table above.

Table2 has only First names and last names. (subset of table1).

I need to match the names from table2 with names in table1 and return their IDs??? This is just a sample. My tables are large so I need an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Questions: what should happen if a (first_name, last_name) appears in the first table more than once (with different id's)? This possibility is exactly why you need id's in the first place. What should your query show in that case? And what should the query show if a (first_name, last_name) from the second table is not found anywhere in the first table?

Comment: why dont you make a where condition to check against both table's 1 and table's 2 first name and last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a plain `INNER JOIN`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
       inner join table2 t2
         on(t1.first_name = t2.first_name and t1.last_name = t2.last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will show all the rows from the first table where the first name and the last name appear in the second table. The operation is called a **semi** join. For a given row from the first table, the "joining" stops as soon as a match is found in the second table. (In a standard join, searching will continue even after a match is found, since the join must find **all** matches - even if **we** know there is only one match, Oracle doesn't know that so it must continue searching.)

```
select t1.* 
from   t1
where  (first_name, last_name) in (select first_name, last_name from t2);
```